# How many maps can exist between two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I'm working on the following exercise. Why does the solution omit applying induction on $n$? That is, assume $P(n)$ and then use that assumption to prove $P(n + 1)$.

[image]

Comment: "Suppose that E has m + 1 elements" is the inductive step.

Comment: In this particular problem it turns out to be easier to use induction on $m$ than on $n$.  Given the functions from $m$ elements to $n$, it's easy to see how to extend each one to get a function from $m+1$ elements to $n$.  It's harder, given the functions from $m$ elements to $n$, to get the functions from $m$ elements to $n+1$.

Comment: And why would they perform induction on $n$? Its a straight forward observation that every additional element added to $F$ maybe mapped to any one of the number of elements in $E$ (that is $n$).

Comment: What is being shown is that a sentence of the form $\forall n \; S(m,n)$ implies $\forall n\; S(m+1,n)$  starting with $m=1.$ ......$\forall n  \; S(1,n)$ is "There are $n$ distinct functions from a singleton set to a set with $n$ members," which is assumed to be obvious.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Just playing devil's advocate so I can guarantee I understand the problem: While manipulating $m$ is certainly easier, why isn't it necessary to prove induction for both variables. Shouldn't we show that $n$, and not just $m$, can take on all natural numbers? Or is that somehow implicit in the proof of $m$?

Comment: The proof works for any $n$.  No need for induction on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @RobertIsrael in the comments, in this particular problem, it's easier to do the induction on $m$ because it's easy to assign an extra element in $E$ to an element in $F$ while it's not that straightforward the other way around.

I must admit though, this problem can be easily solved without the help of induction. Note that you can assign any of the $m$ elements of $E$ to any of the $n$ elements of $F$. That is, there are $n$ choices for each of the $m$ elements. As the choices are independent, the total number of possible maps is $n^m$.

EDIT: As noted in the comments, the alternative method does include induction and is actually similar to the previous logic. Just that the induction is not explicitly used. The combinatorial argument used is based on induction.

Comment: While your first paragraph is correct, your second one is not, because induction is necessary for this result. Your alternative method is right, but it does use induction. Without induction you cannot prove the claim that having a sequence of $m$ choices each of which has $n$ options independently gives a total of $n^m$ options.

Comment: Without using induction explicitly, I meant. I'm just gonna edit it anyway. Thanks for pointing out. @user21820

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Comment: @SayantanSantra Why is induction needed to prove that counting principle? Is it that induction allows us to extend, onto every $m$, $n$ choices? If this is true, how would the second hypothesis of the "induction theorem" be represented here? Show that, if the $k$th element has n choices, then the $k + 1$th element has n choices? I don't see a relationship between either element. Thanks!

Comment: @SayantanSantra This is more clear: Why is induction needed to prove that counting principle? Is it that induction allows us to extend, onto every $m$, $n$ choices? If this is true, how would the second hypothesis of the "induction theorem" be represented here? Show that, if the $k$th element has n choices, then the $k + 1$th element has n choices? I don't see how the inductive hypothesis could be extended onto the $k+1$th case, simply because I see no relationship between either case. Thanks!

Comment: @Muno That's what I said. We don't use the axiom of induction explicitly. But, the concept is used while trying to combining the cases. Imagine it like this: The process of multiplication is true for 2 elements. We can check it easily. Next, we use induction to extend it to $m$ elements. The use of induction might seem unnecessary as the fact we're trying to prove is quite intuitive. But, that COULD be a way to put it.